# How to add a function with print in print

Tags: python

When I'm doing this:

```
def pencil():
   print("pencil")

print("A", pencil())
```

Output showing:

```
pencil
A None
```

I tried some things but nothing worked.

Comment: It's because the function "pencil" is returning None. Instead of printing "pencil" inside your function, return "pencil".

Comment: It would help to show what you want to happen. Best guess is you want a single line `A pencil`. Correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def pencil():
    return "pencil"


print("A", pencil()) # A pencil
```

Or

```
def pencil():
    print("pencil")


print("A") # A
pencil()   # pencil
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```py
print("A", pencil())
```

you are basically asking python to print "A" and the *return value* of the function named `pencil`.

Because you do not specify a `return` statement in your function definition, python returns `None`, hence the unwanted result.

As stated by other people, you just need to `return "pencil"` from the function so that the desired outcome can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

The default return value of a function is `None`
Your function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it will return `None`
Furthermore, `print` returns `None` to as it prints its input to the `sys.stdout` stream. So returning `print("pencil")` would also give you `None`

In order for you to get a value from a function you need to use the `return` statement and return a value. In your case `"pencil"`:

```py
def pencil():
    return "pencil"

print("A", pencil())
```